# MSAccess OnClick Triggers stop working after changing RecordSource

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I use some vba script in a secondary form to blank the recordsource of the primary form, recreate the source table, and then set the recordsource back as the replaced table.

```
Forms("mainfrm").RecordSource = ""
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Create_Customers_Main"
Forms("mainfrm").RecordSource = "select * from Local_Customers_Main"
```

This disables the OnClick events on the primary form until a blank area of the form has been clicked.

Does anyone have a work around for this problem?

continue to flourish,

Phillip

Comment: Have you tried a Repaint of the primary from or possibly a DoEvents on the secondary form after setting the recordsource ? Is the secondary form Modal ?

Comment: Why recreate `Local_Customers_Main` instead of emptying it (by executing `DELETE FROM Local_Customers_Main`) and then loading the new data with an "append query"?  And avoid changing form's `RecordSource`

Comment: repaint and doevents don't solve the problem, neither does changing the secondary form to modal or not. I changed the code to empty the table and refill it, this has sped up the performance of my forms but has still not solved the problem. I think i'm going to resort to putting invisible buttons on the top of the tabs i'm trying to click. Thank you for your advice